# Error when git push to dokku app - fatal: 'test-app' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, deployment, dokku

I have created a dokku app using and initialize it as git
`dokku apps:create test-app`
`dokku git:initialize test-app`

I have done all previous ssh key configuration correctly and also adding the corresponding remote.

My current remote is: **dokku:test-app** where dokku corresponde to the IP of my server
But when I push to the remote, I am having this errors.

**fatal: 'test-app' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

Answer (score 0):

I have always used these git commands in this order, I hope it can help you:

```bash
git init

git remote add origin <url>

git checkout -b main

git add .

git commit -m ""

git fetch origin main

git merge origin/main --allow-unrelated-histories

git commit -m "Merge remote 'main' into local 'main'"

git push origin main
```